# Element doesn't show on smartphone

Tags: css, wordpress, image, responsive-design, slider

Here's my wordpress : http://shopmanouchek.com

I've added a slider using the plugin cyclone slider. 
But on smartphone it doesn't show at all, tablets are ok.

The slider is already on responsive mode, can someone help me?

**UPDATE**

The problem is the height = 0 on smartphone, I tried to add height = xxx px with firebug and it works, how can I change that on the php side now ?

```
        <?php elseif ( 'vimeo' == $slide['type'] ) : ?>
            <div class="cycloneslider-slide cycloneslider-slide-vimeo" <?php echo cyclone_slide_settings($slide, $slider_settings); ?> style="padding-bottom:<?php echo $slider_settings['height']/$slider_settings['width']*100;?>%">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I far as I see, when it's displayed in a mobile size a height:0 it's assigned to a cyclone element. I hope this help.

### UPDATE

The problem is on the style.css file. In the line 1717 you have defined .homepage-banner{ display:none}. But when you see the page from a desktop then this rule is overridden by a media query.

You could change this style or override it on your custom file like this:

```
.homepage-banner{
  display:block;
}
```